# Don't play sound if another sound is being played - C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

Is there a way to say C++ PlaySound function that you don't want to play the sound if another sound is being played at the moment of calling?
Is there any SND_ tag that I can use for this?

Help please!
Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no SND tag for that. But you could use the CoreAudioAPI (supported since windows vista) to check whether a sound is played. You could enumerate the audio sessions or you could use the peakmeter.

Comment: You can use `FMOD`. It's easy to use and it can do everything that you want